# problem while creating button with many divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, menu

[image: screenshot]

This is the menu I'm trying to build. Now I'm confused and can't figure out how to make it.

One div (blue arrow) needs negative margin to get outside the box, another div for blue button background and inside the button two another divs or spans for the text colors. But on hover they need to look same (white color).

I've tried many times to build it but i failed. I get some bugs while loading. Maybe it need any jquery code but I'm very new on it, and I have no idea what to do.

I'm working local and I can't give any link to show it, but there is an image of what I want to make.

I hope you understand me because my English is not good.

Comment: Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your current code so we can work on it, because your explanation isn't very clear.

Comment: You can make an example at www.jsfiddle.net so we can see your code.

Comment: Sadly, jsfiddle [seems to be down](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://jsfiddle.net/). It's been dogging for me all morning.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: A bit of a problem for me. Probably half my answers have links to it..

Comment: It's exactly the reason why question/answers should always contain the full code, and not just be a link to a demo.

Comment: I strongly believe that he wants to know about the wireframe and how to cut it from psd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See:** http://jsbin.com/ihugut

This works in all modern browsers, and IE8+ (it degrades reasonably in IE7).

*(**edit:** it turned out that this must work perfectly in IE7, so see the end of my answer for that solution)*

The one problem you might have is that because I aimed to keep the HTML as simple as possible, the CSS is complicated, so it could be difficult to make changes.

**HTML:**

```
<ol id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Ballina g</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Konferenca g</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Folesit g</a></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 50px;
    background: #aaa
}
#menu {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: num;
    background: #444;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    font: bold 19px sans-serif
}
#menu li {
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    float: left;
    clear: both;

}
#menu a {
    counter-increment: num;
    padding: 3px 15px 3px 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    color: #0cf;
    text-decoration: none
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #fff
}
#menu a:before {
    content: counter(num, decimal-leading-zero);
    color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
    font-weight: normal
}
#menu a:hover:before {
    color: #fff;
}
#menu li:hover {
    background: #0cf;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: 5px
}
#menu li:hover a {
    left: 5px
}
#menu a:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #0cf
}
```

---

Here's a version that works fully in IE7: http://jsbin.com/ihugut/3

The HTML had to be **defiled**:

```
<ol id="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>01</span>Ballina g<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>02</span>Konferenca g<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>03</span>Folesit g<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Amazing! That's some hardcore commitment! You actually created the arrow in css too.. Woow! (and I'm not easily impressed!) Much respect to this answer!

Comment: yes im impressed to! but i need the arrow to be image and supported from all browsers except ie6. so is there another way to do this? and what to you think for Kokos's answer can i do this with that code?

Comment: +1 for the *content* property with the counter. Really neat feature! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user713190: I'll update my answer to work with IE7, but a lot of things I used aren't supported in IE7. It will be a lot less elegant than it is now.

Comment: @thirtydot: thank you very much for trying to help me, im waiting for your update.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've got a good clue of what you want to do. If I understand correctly your problem is everything turning white on hover.

There should be one div that contains all the others, you can change its children on hover without using Javascript like so.

If you for example have this HTML:

```
<div class="parent">

    <span class="child_black">I'm black</span>
    <span class="child_red">I'm red</span>

</div>
```

You would use the following CSS to change the color of both children to white on hover:

```
.child_black {
    color: #000;
}

.child_red {
    color: #f00;
}

.parent:hover .child_black, .parent:hover .child_red {
    color: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ptUkg/

You can use the same technique to show and hide the blue arrow on the left.

For just the color this would work too, but not for the arrow:
*just for the sake of alternatives, I wouldn't recommend this*

```
.parent:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```